# jQuery drop down menu not toggling on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a responsive dropdown menu animated through jQuery in my Rails app, but it's getting stuck on the open position when I follow one of the menu links. I can keep following links, but the menu remains open.

In my application.html.erb:

```
 <header>
    <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
  </header>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <% if current_user %>
      <li><%= image_tag @user.profile_picture.thumb.url, class: 'profile_thumb' %>  <span><%= current_user.email %></span></li>
    <% end %>
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Pledges", pledges_path %></li>
    <% if current_user %>
      <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Register",  new_user_registration_path %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

My jQuery in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.menu').hide();

  $('.hamburger').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle('slow'); 
  });

});
```

It's located in app/assets/javascripts, linked in the head of application.html.erb as such:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it, it is a turbolinks issue. Depending on your version of rails wrap it in the following instead.

```
var ready = function() {

  $('.menu').hide();

  $('.hamburger').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle('slow'); 
  });

};

$(document).on('ready', ready);
// Rails 5 || Turbolinks 5
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
// Rails 4 || Turbolinks < 5
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ropeney. That fixed things up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the default click event before:

```
 $('.hamburger').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').slideToggle('slow'); 
  });
```